# Load website resources before displaying the website

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, load

I want to load resources before displaying the website, something like this

http://atanaiplus.cz/index_en.html

What are the steps to make

1-Make the loading process increase while loading other resources?

2-Load resources in the background

Comment: That is not a trivial task. Break your request down into more specific questions -- it's overly broad and will get closed.

Comment: I edit it to let someone tell me what I should do for this process.

Comment: That site controls its loading with a `Loader()` function in JavaScript in this file: http://atanaiplus.cz/assets/js/script.js. It works by preloading images and it estimates the percentage loaded by knowing how many images it will load and the number currently loaded. They do not take into account the time to load other resources, like the jQuery library and CSS files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a loading screen while site content loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244183/how-to-display-a-loading-screen-while-site-content-loads)