# Loading layout before the content is loaded

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is more of a query than a code issue. I hope I'm not breaking the rules here.

Currently my bootstrap website blocks load on places where it shouldn't be until the website is completely loaded. Wondering if there's a way out here so it loads the layout first and then the content later.

My website currently loads in about 1.5s but the first 1 second makes it look really bad.

regards,

Comment: With firebug or (probably with some other inspecting tool) you can see which of your content is taking much time to load. Also a loading sign before all contents loads could be alternative choice [Here is how to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244183/how-to-display-a-loading-screen-while-site-content-loads)

Comment: There could be a lot of reason your site loads slow and there are a lot of possible solutions. If your site loading slow because it is image heavy you could try lazy loading the images. EITHER way we need to see your html markup to help.

Comment: Give us a link, but I'd venture to guess your javascript might be loading out of order. Load js that must load before the html in the head, and load all other scripts before the closing body tag.